# Why is the modulus operand not working on inputted variables in my C code?

Tags: c

I'm not new to C or anything, I was just doing a couple of exercises when...

```
    for (i=0;i<no_1;i++)
    {
        if (no_1%i==0)
        {
            number_1=i;
        }
```

This program is meant to display the highest common factor of two inputted numbers. The problem is, my code keeps stopping after the user inputs the second number, and I get this option to send an error report to Microsoft (I'm using Windows XP)

I've stripped all my code and realized that it was the modulus operator that was causing my program to stop, but I honestly don't see why. I tried using the modulus operator in a program by itself where I test if `10%2==0`. That worked fine. So by deduction,my problem must be because the numbers I'm using are variables inputted by the user. But then why would it still not work? Am I missing some golden rule or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the following:

```
for (i=0;i<no_1;i++)
```

Start the counter from `1`:

```
for (i=1;i<no_1;i++)
```

You are currently causing a [*divide-by-zero*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero) error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
int main()
{
    int no_1,no_2,number_1=0,number_2=0,i,j;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&no_1);

    printf("\nEnter another number: ");
    scanf("%d",&no_2);

    for (i=1;i<no_1;i++)
    {
        if (no_1%i==0)
        {
            number_1=i;
        }
    }

    for ( j=1;j<no_2;j++)
    {
        if (no_2%j==0)
        {
            number_2=j;
        }
    }

    if (number_1==number_2)
        printf("The HCF is %d",number_1);

    else
        printf("The HCF is 1");

        return 0;
}
```

It's happening because you've start your counter from `0`, it causes the **division by zero** error. Start the counter from `1` for both of your `loop.`